# scrolled text python change ceratin background text

Tags: python, tkinter, background, scrolledwindow

i am trying to program text editor by using tkinter.
this is the mark function:

```
self.text.tag_add("Mark",tk.SEL_FIRST,tk.SEL_LAST)
self.text.tag_config("Mark",background="yellow",foreground="black")
```

and this is the unmark function

```
self.text.tag_add("UnMark",tk.SEL_FIRST,tk.SEL_LAST)
self.text.tag_config("UnMark",background="white",foreground = "black")
```

but the problem is when i mark the text and then unmark it, i cant mark it again.
the mark function dont work when i try to mark the text again that i unmarked it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because the "UnMark" tag has a higher priority than the "Mark" tag. You can add the "Mark" tag, but the configuration of "UnMark" takes precedence.

I recommend instead of an "UnMark" tag, you simply remove the "Mark" tag when you don't want something to be marked.

Comment: There is a way to get the position of a word without use sel_first?

Comment: Get the position by char or something instead of sel_first, for the “config” function

Comment: @OfekRozenkrantz: I don't understand your question. `sel_first` is for finding the start of the selection. That might be a word or it might not be a word. The text widget has the ability to search, via the `search` method. I don't know what finding a word has to do with adding and removing tags, which is what this question was about.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply to me,the information of search methon was useful to me.  i decided add a tag for each character, and remove the tag for each character that selected. i used the search method for find the index of each char that selected.